# Graphic novel about an immortal watcher living through the eons in a library

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to track down a graphic novel I read about 7 or so years ago. The protagonist was an immortal watcher who kind of nudged the course of history at several points in time and had a limited ability to rewind time. He also could teleport to and from his home which was this tower-like library with floor to ceiling bookcases chronicling his observations.

I remember that he burned Cortez's ships in a flashback but the central conflict is him trying to stop a grey goo incident with a nanite experiment escaping a lab.

It was mostly narrated by an unseen villain who was foiling his efforts to guide history in a productive way.

I seem to remember it's maybe ten years old, I think it was relatively new when I read it.

I also seem to vaguely remember Neil Gaiman may have been involved? Or maybe just wrote a little blurb praising it? That's the detail I'm fuzziest on, I may be completely misremembering that part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could it be [*Days Missing*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7261751-days-missing-volume-1) by Phil Hester, et al?

Here is the description from Goodreads:

> Since the beginning of time, there has existed a being whose interaction and interference with mankind has shaped human history. His powers of time and intellect have allowed his secrecy and resulted in certain days being absent from any historical record. Their stories have never been told. Their details have never been documented. Their existence is not remembered. But, the occurrences of these days have forever changed the course of humanity's evolution. These are the "Days Missing" from our existence, and they are about to be revealed.

Found by Googling `"graphic novel" "nanites" burned ships`.

EDIT: Looking a bit more closely, [Chapter 4 of Volume 1](http://www.daysmissing.com/volume1/) is specifically about Cortez.  Also, the series appears to be published by Roddenberry Entertainment which may explain your memory of someone famous being involved.

Comment: That is definitely it, but I sure couldn't find it and I googled a lot. Maybe got re-indexed since the last time I searched? At any rate, thanks! I can't award the bounty since I didn't create it, but you definitely found it.